# Yii 2 The directory does not exist on shared enviroment

Tags: web-hosting, yii2

I have problem with my web site, when i try to access it says

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 

'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'The directory does not exist: C:\HostingSpaces\zerguttnalog\zergutt.com' 
in C:\HostingSpaces\zerguttnalog\zergutt.com\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php:224 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\HostingSpaces\zerguttnalog\zergutt.com\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(358): yii\base\Module->setBasePath('C:\\HostingSpace...') 
#1 C:\HostingSpaces\zerguttnalog\zergutt.com\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(223): yii\base\Application->setBasePath('C:\\HostingSpace...') 
#2 C:\HostingSpaces\zerguttnalog\zergutt.com\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(202): yii\base\Application->preInit(Array) 
#3 C:\HostingSpaces\zerguttnalog\zergutt.com\wwwroot\index.php(12): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array) 
#4 {main} thrown in C:\HostingSpaces\zerguttnalog\zergutt.com\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php on line 224.
```

On my local machine everything is ok (xampp on windows), i don't know what is happening on the server. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you run composer install/update on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have set the base path of your application to (C:\HostingSpace..), it will work fine on your local machine because the directory exists, but on a different server yii will not find this directory.

Check your configuration files, you will fine a line starts with.
`'basePath' => ...` you need to change it to `'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),` and hopefully it will work fine.